# What are hypo modes, related to standard guitar?

Tags: guitar

Relating to guitar what are hypo modes?

Comment: Looks like this is what you're talking about: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypodorian_mode The modes are the same as in any other kind of music.

Comment: Could you add to or clarify your question? Modes and scales "are" just ideas, and the instrument doesn't change the notes that they're made up of. Or do you have a question about technique?

Comment: Also: In the medieval "church" modes, every mode had a "sibling" starting with the prefix "hypo." The "hypo" version started a perfect fourth lower, but had the same pattern of whole and half steps. See https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/35756/how-did-the-plagal-modes-differ-from-their-authentic-counterpart-in-practice

Comment: Here's another partly-relevant recent question that elaborates on what @AndyBonner said. W/R/T guitar, the only difference might be whether or not you can reach the upper or lower pitches: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/117925/what-does-plagal-actually-mean-for-modal-music-and-melody-generally